# JavaScript : does setInterval() effects the computation speed?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have used Intervals in 2 - 3 places. I am not sure, but, does it really effects the computation speed of java script ? Any body can explain me the concept, if YES or NO, will be help full to optimize my code. I have lots of computation in my code so will be useful if I can optimize.

Those who searching for code please do not respond to this. I need only concept behind Intervals.

Answer (score 0):

> The setInterval() method calls a function or evaluates an expression
>   at specified intervals (in milliseconds).
>
> The setInterval() method will continue calling the function until
>   clearInterval() is called, or the window is closed.
>
> The ID value returned by setInterval() is used as the parameter for
>   the clearInterval() method.
>
> Tip: 1000 ms = 1 second.
>
> Tip: To execute a function only once, after a specified number of
>   milliseconds, use the setTimeout() method.

source [link](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp). 
Well, its up to you how you are using this function and your question is not cleared also.

Comment: I Just want to know whether it will decrease the execution speed or not. If there are already lots of compuation going on

Comment: What is the functionality in that function/code which is with setInterval() ?

Comment: Obaid, I cant write it to you bcoz its an complete app there alots of places where I have used setInterval, what matters for me is if I will remove Intervals and use some other logic for doing same thing, does its speed increses or not.

Comment: are you calling ajax request on setInterval()?

Answer (score 0):

`setInterval()` [probably calls the provided function repeatedly, ignoring errors and calls functions repeatedly even if they take longer than the interval you set to run.](http://zetafleet.com/blog/why-i-consider-setinterval-harmful)

In answer to your question, `setInterval()` calls some function, which by virtue that it's some kind of computation may noticeably slow down the browser. Note that if you have to do some periodic computation, `setInterval()`, `setTimeout()`, or your own *sane* homebrew solution wouldn't make a performance difference.